# I Can't show code highlight in Gitbook

Tags: gitbook

I just installed Prism in gitbook and set in book.json,then it showed in web editor correctly[Shows in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVQBJ.png),but it doesn't work when i  [read it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLgGR.png)...
And the Update log are going well with no mistake.

Paragraph in Editor:

````
```csharp
abstract class ContinentFactory
{
public abstract Herbivore CreateHerbivore();
public abstract Carnivore CreateCarnivore();
}
```
````

Code in book.json:

```
{
"plugins": ["-highlight","prism"] 
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample code what you have tried. please be specific .

Comment: I edited. Is that suitable?